# How to debug a node.js app with gulp tasks in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, node-debugger

I'd like to enable debugging with a node.js app using Walmart's Electrode framework: http://www.electrode.io/

I can simply set the debug configuration to watch `server/index.js`, but I don't know if that is the right way considering all the gulp tasks that need to run with compiling and other magic. Should I configure WebStorm to do a gulp build before running `server/index.js`?

I tried creating a gulp configuration using both gulp dev and dev-static but that doesn't seem to trigger the breakpoints.